# clojure map over sequence of pairs

Tags: clojure

```
 (def tmp = [ 1 2 3 9 4 8])
```

I'm trying to create pairs of 2, then for each pair, subtract the second number from the first.
desired result: (1 6 4)

Here is what I was trying:

```
(map #(apply - %2 %1) (partition 2 tmp))
```

how can I do this?

Comment: From the example it looks like you subtract the *first* number from the *second*, not the other way around, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Partition produces a sequence of sequences so the function you map over them needs to expect a sequence of two items. There are several ways to express this:

```
(def tmp  [ 1 2 3 9 4 8])

user> (map #(- (second %) (first %)) (partition-all 2 tmp ))
(1 6 4)

user> (map #(apply - (reverse %)) (partition-all 2 tmp ))
(1 6 4)

user> (map (fn [[small large]] (- large small)) (partition-all 2 tmp ))
(1 6 4)
```

The version using apply is different because it will still "work" on odd length lists:

```
user> (map #(apply - (reverse %)) (partition-all 2 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] ))
(1 1 1 -7)
```

The others will crash on invalid input, which you may prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `reduce`

```
(reduce #(conj %1 (apply - (reverse %2)))  [] (partition-all 2 [1 2 3 9 4 8])) 
=> [1 6 4]
```

Comment: (reduce (conj ...)) ia a cool way to express a non-lazy version of map. Check out the new reducers library for a bunch more on this topic: http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why this solution was overlooked...

Since switching the order of subtraction is simply the negative of the original subtraction, (a-b=-(b-a)),
the solution becomes more efficient (only in this particular case!!)

```
(map #(- (apply - %)) (partition-all 2 [1 2 3 9 4 8]))
```

Pedagogically, Arthur's solution is correct. This is just a solution that is more suited the specfic question.